# Hiding email signatures in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, plugins, email-signature, readability

Is there any setting or plugin that's capable of detecting and hiding most signatures so that threads become much more readable?

I suppose the best answer to this need would be something that hides them behind some kind of link, so that we may still see a signature on demand.

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly what you want but [Xobni](http://www.xobni.com/) is a plugin for Outlook, one thing it can do is simplify a conversation get rid if signature, pictures etc and just have the text

[image]