# Can I change other users' fonts upon local display in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, fonts, plugins, microsoft-office-2007

Is there an Outlook plugin, or any other method (*), for never looking at another email that uses fourteen point Comic Sans, Arial, or Times New Roman?

> Basically, I would like to open someone's email, and (even though they enjoyed every moment typing it in some heinous, illegible font on some visually offensive stationary) it displays on my monitor in something more readable?

- Does Outlook have a plug-in that re-themes others' emails to a user determined font?
- Is there some way of creating a reading pane view that re-themes emails?

I am looking for something [similar to the detail-level function of Xobni](https://superuser.com/q/64476/46516), only I am basically trying to hide style features; minimally replacing with my system's default, or maximally something user specified that doesn't give me tiny seizures and looks nice. (Particular version - Outlook for Office Professional Plus 2007 SP2)

*(`*`: Any other method would **not** include ripping out the offending sender's system fonts, or anything proactive and team-oriented like that)*

Comment: By chance, can you share with us what version of Outlook you are using?

Comment: @CharlieRB Outlook for Office Professional Plus 2007 SP2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use **Conditional Formatting** to do this. Select View -> Arrange By -> Custom... to open the Customize View dialog box:

[image]

Many formatting properties can be set within the properties of these functions. This information is from [Office Tool Tips - Conditional formatting](http://www.officetooltips.com/outlook_2007/tips/conditional_formatting.html) which gives additional instructions.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this only adjusts the display of the messages pane; the body of the viewing pane or open messages is unaffected