# Hide email signatures in Outlook 2016

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016, email-signature

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/64476/hiding-email-signatures-in-outlook) basically asks the same, but is ancient and only has one answer that points to a [plugin that is no longer supported](http://address.yahoo.com/xobni) from a company that has since been bought by Yahoo...

My company has mandatory email signatures that are quite large in size, (between 20 - 24 lines) and often much much longer than the mail itself.
Long email threads are already not my favorite thing in the world, but the signatures just clutter the entire thread and make it very hard to follow a conversation.

Is there a setting or plugin for Outlook 2016 that removes all these mail signatures that clog up the thread?

**TL;DR; Can I hide email signatures in Outlook 2016 through a setting or plugin?**

Comment: Since it's possible to add text an email, then it's possible to remove text from email, this can indeed be done with a custom plugin

Comment: Have an upvote from me, I've just arrived here from a browse to find a solution for this very problem. Often a chain of emails will run to  multiple pages and would easily fit a single page if all the noise could be switched off. I'm trying to move our internal chatter to Discourse, but clients will still use email for the forseeable future. Don't get me started on sorting all the attachments!

Comment: From my experience outlook is not able to differentiate signatures from the rest of the mail text. I would imagine you would have to find a plugin that can do it, outlook won't have a setting.

Answer (score 0):

I think using standard signature block will help. Here is short description from [this site](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-use-the-standard-email-signature-delimiter-1171204):

"The "standard" that is widely used on Usenet, but also with email, is

```
"-- " (two dashes followed by a white-space character) on a line by itself.
```

If you use this as the first line of you email signature, almost all mail software and webmail clients know not to display your signature again in replies and long mail threads."

Hope this helps.